# Como renderizar novamente meu botão no react native?

Tags: react-native

Tenho esse botão que deve ter um background-color dependendo do estado:

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={this._onPressButtonMassa}>
  <View style={[styles.button, this.props.hipertrofia === 'sim' ?
  { backgroundColor: 'black' } : { backgroundColor: 'white' }]}>
     <Icon name="bicycle" size={50} color="#FAFAFA" />
     <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Quero ganhar massa</Text>
  </View>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Quando clico nesse botão o estado é alterado:

```
  _onPressButtonMassa = () => {
    this.setState({ hipertrofia: 'sim' }); 
    this.setState({ perdapeso: 'nao' }); 
  };
```

Porém o botão se inicia com o background-color white, e quando o estado é alterado ele não realiza a renderização do botão novamente, continuando branco independente do valor de `this.props.hipertrofia`

Como posso fazer pra renderizar novamente meu botão pra que ele altere para a o `background-color` black quando clicar nele?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você está apontando para this.props.hipertrofia, por isso não está alterando...

Estabeleça o valor do state hipertrofia para this.props.hipertrofia no constructor, e no seu button, troque this.props.hipertrofia para this.state.hipertrofia

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props); //importante chamar super(props)!

  this.state = {
    hipertrofia: this.props.hipertrofia
    perdapeso: this.props.perdapeso
    //outros estados
  }
}

_onPressButtonMassa = () => {
  this.setState({ hipertrofia: 'sim' }); 
  this.setState({ perdapeso: 'nao' }); 
};

<TouchableOpacity onPress={this._onPressButtonMassa}>
  <View style={[styles.button, this.state.hipertrofia === 'sim' ?
  { backgroundColor: 'black' } : { backgroundColor: 'white' }]}>
  //...
```